# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular

[toggleserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH65c.jpg)

//////!this code is not working showing the error [Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string']////////////need a little help
toggleserverstatus () {

```
this.statusflag = !this.statusflag;

if (this.statusflag ==  true) {

  this.serverstatus='online';
}
return this.serverstatus;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotes around the initial assignment of what you wanted to be False to statusflag. `'false'` is not the same as `False`.